# HOST_THEMES not working in my mezzanine project

Tags: django, django-cms, mezzanine

I have a `mezzanine` project where I have added multiple themes to it.
Now I want to add the feature of `HOST_THEMES` but it isn't working and I am unable to find the solution for this.

[image: My project Directory with <code>flat</code> and <code>moderna</code> themes]

And this is how I have added the themes to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and `HOST_THEMES` are added with the `host` and `theme`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "flat",
    "moderna",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    # "mezzanine.accounts",
    # "mezzanine.mobile",
)

HOST_THEMES = [('localhost', 'moderna'),]
```

**Problem -** Only `flat` theme is being loaded as default even I have used `HOST_THEMES`. Do I need to change some other setting also?

Comment: I don't see `moderna` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @solarissmoke sorry for that updated that still it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your settings.py contains:

```
"loaders": [
                "mezzanine.template.loaders.host_themes.Loader",
                "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
                "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
            ]
```

Example below

```
 TEMPLATES = [
        {
            "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
            "DIRS": [
                os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates")
            ],
            "OPTIONS": {
                "context_processors": [
                    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                    "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                    "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                    "django.template.context_processors.static",
                    "django.template.context_processors.media",
                    "django.template.context_processors.request",
                    "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                    "mezzanine.conf.context_processors.settings",
                    "mezzanine.pages.context_processors.page",
                ],
                "builtins": [
                    "mezzanine.template.loader_tags",
                ],
                "loaders": [
                    "mezzanine.template.loaders.host_themes.Loader",
                    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
                    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
                ]
            },
        },
    ]
```

source:
https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/a6d425b5d318446d2711883f9c0db244c7e8d063/mezzanine/project_template/project_name/settings.py